# Have I simplifed $ \bar AB + ABC\bar D + AB\bar CD + AB(C \oplus D) + CD(A \oplus B) $ correctly?

Tags: solution-verification, boolean-algebra, boolean

Please verify my simplified boolean expression and let me know if it is correct, or if we can further simplify?

[Simplifying Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT1Yg.png)

I have further simplified it:

[Further Simplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnStG.png)